# Cannot use HttpRequest<any> as option in the http client request

Tags: angular, http-headers, migration, httprequest, httpclient

I'm try to migrate my angular project from **HttpModule** to **HttpClientModule**, but I have trouble with the header request, so many times I thought I understand what is going on here. So what I want to do at this moment is moving small bit at a time to HttpClient, that means I am not using **HttpInterceptor** and I try use the idea from HttpModule where we can use **RequestOptions** in the http request (`this.http.get(url, requestOptions)`). From what I read about **HttpInterceptor**, I thought I could use **HttpRequest** as my options in the *http client request*. This is how I construct my method.

```
get(url:string, options: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpRequest<any>> {
 return this.httpClient.get(url, this.getHeader(options));
}

getHeader(options: HttpRequests<any>): HttpRequests<any> {
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 if(options && options.headers && option.headers instanceOf HttpHeaders) {
  headers = options.headers;
 }
 headers.append('authorization': 'abc');
 let params: new HttpParams().set('id', this.id);
 let headerOptions = {
  params: params,
  headers: headers,
  withCredential: true,
 }
 Object.keys(options).forEach(key => {
  if ( !(key===params && key===headers && key===withCredential) ) {
   headersOption[key] = options[key];
  }
 });
 return headersOption as HttpRequest;
}
```

In the visual studio code, it complains about the headers type is not the same as the passing params. So Is other way I can do this to get those parameters into my header request?

Comment: The `.get` function does not take an `HttpRequest` as one of its params, however if you remove the `HttpRequest` typing from the places you've used it, it should work

Comment: According to this, it takes options as parameter, and it he header. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient

Comment: That's right, but not an `HttpRequest`. As I say, if you remove where you've typed it as `HttpRequest`, then it should work as the structure is correct.

Comment: Oh!!! Thanks, is there other way I can introduce native interface or classes as my paramedic?

Comment: No, unfortunately not as `HttpClient` has not defined any type for the options.

Comment: Appreciate it, if you answer below I will accept as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[`HttpClient#get`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get)** function does not allow `HttpRequest` as one of it parameters.

While the options do share most of the same properties as `HttpRequest`, they cannot be used interchangeably.

If you remove where you've added the `HttpParams` type, the code should compile without issue.